# Arithmetic overflow error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this error message

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Here is my code:

```
-- Set Variabes --
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(3) = 'L20'
DECLARE @cable int = (SELECT
            cd.id

        FROM
            dbo.WTG_ID wd JOIN
            dbo.power_wtg p ON wd.id = p.wtgid,
            dbo.data d JOIN
            dbo.Cable_ID cd ON cd.id = d.cable

        WHERE
            wd.name = @name and
            wd.string = cd.string and
            wd.position = cd.wtgs

        GROUP BY 
            cd.id)
-- Query --
select
case   
        WHEN d.KP < 8321.399 THEN '1) K20'
        WHEN d.KP < 8336.499 THEN '2) K20 J-Tube'
        WHEN d.KP < 8356.499 THEN '3) K20 CPS'
        WHEN d.KP < 9392.977 THEN '4) K20 - L20'
        WHEN d.KP < 9412.977 THEN '5) L20 CPS'
        WHEN d.KP < 9428.077 THEN '6) L20 J-Tube'
    else '7) L20'
    end as Location,
case   
        WHEN d.temp < 21 THEN '20'
        WHEN d.temp < 22 THEN '21'
        WHEN d.temp < 23 THEN '22'
        WHEN d.temp < 24 THEN '23'
        WHEN d.temp < 25 THEN '24'
        WHEN d.temp < 26 THEN '25'
        WHEN d.temp < 27 THEN '26'
        WHEN d.temp < 28 THEN '27'
        WHEN d.temp < 29 THEN '28'
        WHEN d.temp < 30 THEN '29'
        WHEN d.temp < 31 THEN '30'
        WHEN d.temp < 32 THEN '31'
    else '32'
    end as temp,
count (d.temp) as [frequency every 2 hours],
count (distinct(datepart(day, d.time))) as [frequency every day],
count (distinct(datepart(week, d.time))) as [frequency every week],
min(d.KP) as 'Min KP',
max(d.KP) as 'Max KP',
avg(d.KP) as 'Avg KP'

from
data d

where
d.temp > 20 and
d.cable = @cable

group by 
case   
        WHEN d.KP < 8321.399 THEN '1) K20'
        WHEN d.KP < 8336.499 THEN '2) K20 J-Tube'
        WHEN d.KP < 8356.499 THEN '3) K20 CPS'
        WHEN d.KP < 9392.977 THEN '4) K20 - L20'
        WHEN d.KP < 9412.977 THEN '5) L20 CPS'
        WHEN d.KP < 9428.077 THEN '6) L20 J-Tube'
    else '7) L20'
    end,
case   
        WHEN d.temp < 21 THEN '20'
        WHEN d.temp < 22 THEN '21'
        WHEN d.temp < 23 THEN '22'
        WHEN d.temp < 24 THEN '23'
        WHEN d.temp < 25 THEN '24'
        WHEN d.temp < 26 THEN '25'
        WHEN d.temp < 27 THEN '26'
        WHEN d.temp < 28 THEN '27'
        WHEN d.temp < 29 THEN '28'
        WHEN d.temp < 30 THEN '29'
        WHEN d.temp < 31 THEN '30'
        WHEN d.temp < 32 THEN '31'
    else '32'
    end

    ORDER BY 
        1 asc, 2 asc

;
```

Comment: What is stored in `d.KP` column? What datatype it is?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DECLARE @cable bigint = (SELECT
        cd.id

    FROM
        dbo.WTG_ID wd JOIN ...etc
```

i suspect your selected cd.id exceeds the maximum integer value - is it a serial number held as a string perhaps?